# How to test a value supplied via the pipeline to a C# cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell-cmdlet

Assuming that I have a C# `Cmdlet` that accepts values from the pipeline:

```
[System.Management.Automation.Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline=true)]
public string Query
{
    get { return query; }
    set { query = value; }
}
private string query;
```

I would test this:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void ShouldReturnAnInfoObjectCollection()
{

    // arrange
    string query = "SELECT si_id, si_name FROM ci_infoobjects WHERE si_id=23";
    InfoObjects actual = null;

    GetInfoObjects cmdlet = new GetInfoObjects();
    cmdlet.Query = query;

    // act
    IEnumerator result = cmdlet.Invoke().GetEnumerator();
    while (result.MoveNext())
    {
        actual = ((InfoObjects)result.Current);
    }

    // assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(InfoObjects));

}
```

How would I test this `Cmdlet`'s ability to accept a value for `Query` via the pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using Pipeline.Input for Powershell testing](http://blog.brianhartsock.com/2009/03/30/using-pipelineinput-for-powershell-testing/) was helpful.

Configure runspace:

```
[ClassInitialize()]
public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
{
    config = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
}
```

Create test:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void Get_InfoObjects_with_multiple_values_from_pipeline()
{

    // "SELECT ..." | Get-InfoObjects ...

    //
    // arrange
    //

    string[] queries = { "SELECT * FROM ci_infoobjects WHERE si_id=23", "SELECT * FROM ci_infoobjects WHERE si_id=4" };

    Command command = new Command("Get-InfoObjects");

    using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(config))
    {

        runspace.Open();

        using (Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
        {

            foreach (string query in queries)
            {
                pipeline.Input.Write(query);
            }

            pipeline.Commands.Add(command);

            //
            // act
            // 

            var actual = pipeline.Invoke();

            //
            // assert
            //

            Assert.AreEqual(1, actual.Count);
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual[0], typeof(System.Management.Automation.PSObject));

        } // using Pipeline
    } // using // Runspace

} // test
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your Cmdlet:

```
[Cmdlet("Load" , "Item", DefaultParameterSetName="Item")]
public class LoadCommand : Cmdlet
{
    private string assembly;

    [Parameter(Mandatory=true, ValueFromPipeline=true, ParameterSetName="Item", Position=0, HelpMessageResourceId="LoadCmdlet_Item")]
    public string Assembly
    {
        get { return assembly; }
        set { assembly = value; }
    }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        base.ProcessRecord();

        if (File.Exists(assembly))
        {
            WriteObject(Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName));
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

you can write a test that passes input to the cmdlet. Here's where the real cmdlet testing occurs:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldLoadAssemblyWithFileName()
{
    string asmFile = this.GetType().Module.FullyQualifiedName;

    LoadCommand cmd = new LoadCommand();
    cmd.Item = asmFile;

    IEnumerator result = cmd.Invoke().GetEnumerator();

    Assert.IsTrue(result.MoveNext());
    Assert.IsTrue(result.Current is Assembly);

    Assert.AreEqual(this.GetType().Assembly.FullName, ((Assembly)result.Current).FullName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I understand how to write a `Cmdlet` that  accepts and process pipeline data.  What I would like to know is how to write a unit test for this.

Comment: Is setting `cmd.Item = asmFile` really a test of that parameter's ability to accept values from the pipeline?

Comment: If by real you mean testing whether it is setting the internal value or not, yes it is. And if you want to perform *REAL* test you can run a powershell snippet from your integration tests. It is like unit testing a powershell script